# Is it possible to add components dynamically to the middle of BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I'm building a small swing application where I've created contentpane with BoxLayout aligned to Y axis and added another 2 JPanels to it. So far so good.

Now I've stumbled upon a problem where I have to re-create the first JPanel and add it to the middle of other two JPanels.

There might be more than one occurrence where another panel is added to the layout so I wish it would expand appropriately.

Conclusion: What I'm looking for is to add components to the BoxLayout with option to add them before the last component.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the `Container` API. The `add(...)` method has overloaded methods that allow you to specify the position of the component in the container. Then `revalidate()` and `repaint()` the panel.

Comment: I should have guessed that it is that simple, well now I know. That proves once again that I should pay more attention to API. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I would simply remove all components and then re-add them in the order desired being sure to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the BoxLayout-using container after you've completed this action.

If you need your GUI itself to change size, then you may have to call `pack()` on the top-level window that holds these components.